# I used FSO to get a file name. But I need the path too. Is it possible to get the path using FSO?

Tags: vb.net

Here is the code I'm using. Hope that it helps pinpoint the area where I need help.

```
    Private Sub readCVS_file()

    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                    FileIO.TextFieldParser(
                      GetTempPath() + "output.tmp")
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try

                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                Dim currentField As String
                For Each currentField In currentRow
                    'get file path using currentField. First field is program name
                Next
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
              FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
    "is not valid.")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using

End Sub
```

After reading the current field, I want to get the path to the filename (filename is the first field in output.tmp text file.)

Thanks for any help...

Comment: extra info... I'm using plain old vb and not any web code.

Comment: Read your question aloud and ask yourself if you could figure out the question based on that.  `I already have the file name` from where? what? If you have the file what's the problem?  How does a pid factor into this?

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was unclear. I will change it. I got the filename using fso. It returned the filename, but not the path. I will look more into the fso and see if I can find a way to get the path. Thanks for letting me know about being unclear. :)

Comment: 1) If you are using VB.NET then you should be using the [System.IO.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes. 2) Are you saying that you have no idea where the file is on the drive and want to search for it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And yes, I do not know where the file is. I'm looking at a way to get it with more fso.I will look into your suggestions and see if I can get it to work. Thanks for taking the time...

Comment: Let me give a better idea of what's going on. I use fso to write to a file. The file contains the file name. I want to read the file name and then get the path to the file.

Comment: This is proving to be harder than I thought. Thanks for those who helped. I don't think I'm going to find an answer soon. Will keep digging....

Comment: [Edit] your post with the code you are using.  Getting the path is pretty easy, but you may not even be using VB.NET

Comment: @user3697824   I put my code in the first post. Maybe it will help. I'm just reading a file that has a filename in it, and I want the path to that filename. Evidently, not an easy thing to do.

Comment: If the path is not in the file your are reading, you will have to search the entire disk for it.  FSO is not a NET thing BTW

Comment: Thanks for your help. Searching the entire disk will take a while, so I'll write that off... And yea, I guess FSO is not really a "net" thing. I just found that it could do things that I could not do in normal vb coding. Before, I was using: Process.GetProcessesByName(p.ProcessName)(0).MainModule.FileName.ToString() But I could not get all the processes.

Comment: @jumper `MainModule.FileName` gives the full path: [ProcessModule Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I guess the full path was lost when the file was created. N.B. a comma is a valid character in a filename, so it may be a poor choice of separator in the file you are reading.